# Python using numpy ~isnan()

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to reduce the following peace of code.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('logfilename.txt')
x = data[:,0]
x = x[~np.isnan(x)]
```

to something like that:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('logfilename.txt')
x = data[~np.isnan(data[:,0])]
```

But that doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Very best

Comment: What do you mean by _that doesn't work_? Please provide any error message you might get.

Comment: `x = data[:,0][~np.isnan(data[:,0])]` would be the equivalent to the above code. but i am not sure what you want to do, where is the error and what is the error.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Following your code, you need to replace `x` with `data[:,0]` so it should be:

```
x = data[:,0][~np.isnan(data[:,0])]
```

That's repetitive, why would you want that? Stay with the first one!